# Bulk renaming files with sort order through Powershell ignores Sorting

Tags: powershell, rename, bulk

Trying to bulk-rename photographs to a given naming scheme while keeping the current sort order with the following code:

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object  -begin { $count=1 }  -process { rename-item $_ -NewName "MyNamingSchemeWithIndex-$count.jp2"; $count++ }
```

The renaming works well, however in some cases, the order gets messed up. I couldn't so far identify any given reason why only some runs are incorrect, expect for the files being jp2 instead of jpeg. With jpeg it so far seems to be right every time.

I tried adding Sort-Object

```
Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object | ForEach-Object  -begin { $count=1 }  -process { rename-item $_ -NewName "MyNamingSchemeWithIndex-$count.jp2"; $count++ }
```

But that doesn't seem to help.

Just running

```
 Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object
```

Works though and displays proper order.

Comment: Can you give a specific example of a set of half a dozen or so file names that don’t process properly?

Comment: It works for me.  Are you expecting a numeric sort `9,10,11`?  Please give an example.  How can you tell what the old names were (aside from `-whatif`)?

Comment: I think you want `sort-object name`.

Comment: There's a lot of confusion about the default output order of get-childitem, and the default properties sort-object sorts by.

Comment: Plus you're modifying the very thing you're looping over (filenames).

Comment: @js2010 that's it indeed. I was stupidly expecting that it would sort by filename by default, not sure what exactly it's sorting on by default, but adding `sort-object name` seems to correctly sort and pipe forward the files, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this?  Making sure to sort by name.  Sort-object also blocks until the whole list is gathered, otherwise I would put (get-childitem) in parentheses, so that it's complete first.  Using -whatif to show what would happen, although it's not always true.  -verbose would show the real result.

```
echo hi | set-content a,b,c
Get-ChildItem | sort-object name | 
  ForEach-object { $count=1 } { 
  rename-item $_ -NewName MyNamingSchemeWithIndex-$count.jp2 -whatif; $count++ }

What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item:
C:\users\admin\foo\a Destination: 
C:\users\admin\foo\MyNamingSchemeWithIndex-1.jp2".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item:
C:\users\admin\foo\b Destination: 
C:\users\admin\foo\MyNamingSchemeWithIndex-2.jp2".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item:
C:\users\admin\foo\c Destination: 
C:\users\admin\foo\MyNamingSchemeWithIndex-3.jp2".
```

Comment: Indeed, `sort-object name` did the trick, no idea what the default sort order was doing. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing problematic sample filenames, the most likely problem is the difference in the way **Explorer** and **PowerShell** sort strings with numbers.

[image: Screenshot 1]

The most reliable way to process files (or folders) in the order displayed in **Explorer** is to have **Explorer** supply the list of filenames. This can be done using the propeties and methods of the[`shell.application`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell) com object.

For simplicity of demonstration, run the following with only a single **Explorer** window open displaying the files you want to process with the desired sort order. This can be a file folder, a *Search Results* window, or a *Library*.

```
$Shell     = New-Object -ComObject shell.application
$WinFolder = @($Shell.Windows())[0].Document.Folder
```

The [folder object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folder) represented by $WinFolder has the [Items() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folder-items). This method returns the items in the order displayed. These [items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folderitem) have both Name and Path properties (among others) -- for processing, you'll most likely want the path, but for demonstration, I'm accessing the name.

So, with the target folder open and sorted by name, in **PowerShell**, use the expression:

- `@($WInFolder.Items()).name`

to list the files in the order they're displayed:

Name ascending:

[image: SS2]

Name descending:

[image: SS3]

Group order respected as well:

[image: SS4]

So, for actual processing, get an ordered list of fully-qualified paths before re-naming, as you don't want to be working with a constantly changing source collection.

```
$Shell     = New-Object -ComObject shell.application
$WinFolder = @($Shell.Windows())[0].Document.Folder

$FilePaths = @($WinFolder.Items()).Path

# Do whatever proceessing you want:

ForEach ($ItemPath in $FilePaths)
{
    ###  Prcess file here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, this is a good idea indeed. Sadly though not applicable here, since the files are using 0-padded numbers. (My bad for not providing sample file names though). Interesting approach though with reading directly off explorer.

Comment: Perhaps not *necessary* in your case, but it *could* be applied to your files and would produce the desireed results. The neat thing is, this method works with any sort order you can produce in **Explorer** that would otherwise require extra coding to reproduce in **PowerShell**, e.g. grouping (as shown), sorting on EXIF metadata such as photos by DateTaken, music by track length or genre, or files from multiple locations. So you might want to put this in your notes -- it's a handy trick to have in your toolbox.

Comment: Yeah it's neat for sure. The only issue a bit is that while doing those operations, I usually have a couple explorer windows open. So that might screw it up a bit/I'd need to figure out how to get the ID of the given Windows.

Comment: That's pretty trivial if they're open to different locations. With a couple of windows open, take a look at `@($shell.WIndows()).LocationName` and  `@($shell.WIndows()).Document.Folder.Self.Path` for starters...